# How can I make code wait for ExternalEvent to perform first ,When an ExternalEvent is Raised , and perform all other tasks after that?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, revit-api

/*When the button is clicked in the fucntion below the External event should execute first , but it is not happening instead it complete all other tasks and then run external event handler. */

//Function

```
        private void BtnClicked()
        {
            btnClickedEvent.Raise();
            Othertasks();
        }
```

//external Event

```
btnClickedEvent = ExternalEvent.Create(new ExternalEventhandle());

    public class ExternalEventhandle: IExternalEventHandler
    {
        public void Execute(UIApplication app)
        {
            UIDocument UIdoc = app.ActiveUIDocument;
            Document doc = UIdoc.Document;
            //----some task to do ------
            RunTestFunction();
        }

        public string GetName()
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

> /*Expectation: Want to excute RunTestFunction() first , only when it is completed then only Run Othertasks() function*/

Comment: Either put the `RunTestFunction()` and `RunOtherTasks()` calls both into the external event handler, or put them both into the `BtnClicked` method? I guess there's a reason why you don't want to do that, so it would help if you include that reason in your question.

Comment: HI @sbridewell, `RunTestFunction()` needs Revit Document, therefore needed an external event so cant add `RunTestFunction()` to button click directly, and `OtherTask()` function makes changes in UI file, there fore if I try to add it to ExternalEvent , then i have to create a new object to use it, which i cant use due some limitations(cant use static here).

Comment: Answer to the above problem: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/when-a-revit-externalevent-is-raised-externalevent-should/td-p/11770124